# Is there a reason not to play your whole hand at once if you can?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Literally our first ever game of Yu Gi Oh, my friend got a hand consisting of 1 normal monster, 1 spell, and 3 traps. She played all 5 on her first turn, emptying her hand, since as far as we could tell there were no rules against it. It felt very strange, coming from MTG, but also odd because there didn't seem to be any strategic reason *not* to do it. Particularly with traps, why would you keep them in your hand rather than get them out on the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can play all your hand if you want and can on your first turn. Don't worry, compared to MTG Yugioh is quite faster, and even has First Turn Kills (more frequent than any FTK that exists in MTG), so it's probably what will seem stranger to you at first.

> Particularly with traps, why would you keep them in your hand rather than get them out on the field?

Depending on your strategy, you may not want to play all your cards at once, even if you could. Why? Well, several reasons, and besides no strict rule on why; this strongly depends on your strategy and way of playing.

However, if you play or set all your cards, then you would be on a *tactical disadvantage*, as your opponent now knows **exactly what kind of cards and how many you have**. In the case of your friend, you now know he indeed has one monster and 4 spells/traps...

This may give your opponent the info they need to counter your moves; it is now obvious that one should attempt to neutralize your backrow (term used to refer to your spell and trap zone).

Another disadvantage is that **your opponent may destroy all the field** with some effect (like my favorite, Black Rose Dragon) and leave you helpless; that is why you should play all your cards only if your strategy requires so in that moment.

---

However, seeing your opponent set 4 spell/traps can be quite alarming or distracting("it's a trap", literally), thus a good strategy if used correctly. Just make sure that if you are bluffing you have a good plan that is worth it.

But, hey, I have in several occasions set my Dark Hole spell card (useless that way) in an attempt to bluff. Combined it with a brief grin and then poker face I have been able to scare the hell out of quite experienced players, or at least make them rethink their moves.

Another behavioral strategy I recommend is to **periodically check your set card(s), as in considering its use in that moment.** This may make your opponent *think you have some powerful trap card* waiting there, and hopefully affect to your advantage the response they take after your provocation. Things like these are key to an effective bluffing, so it is not just set everything and pass.

But yes, you can play all your cards, but strongly consider if it is worth doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of five reasons why it would be disadvantageous to play your whole hand.

1. Your opponent knows you have no cards in hand, and has a good idea of what the cards on the field are - monsters in front, spells and traps in the back, less hidden information - you can't be bluffing an [Honest](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Honest) for example.
2. Full field wipes will be harder to recover from. If you have played all your cards and your opponent destroys everything on the field - such as with [Black Rose Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Rose_Dragon) - you now have no cards left in hand to start rebuilding.
3. Some cards may be better played later - This is turn one, your opponent has played their first monster but the rest of the field is empty, this probably isn't the best time to use your [Dark Hole](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Hole). Some cards are better kept until you can make good use of them, rather than played the first time you can.
4. Limited card space - Unlike magic you have limited space for your cards, 5 in front row, 5 in back row. You may not want to fill up the space, depending on what cards you are playing, so quickly. Play five traps first turn, your opponent plays nothing that triggers any of them, and you can't play that spell you drew second turn.
5. Cards that care about your hand - This one is more of an edge case in my experience but there are cards, like [Tragoedia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tragoedia), that will care about what you have in hand, with no cards in hand it's a 0/0.